# Django not saving immediately on new row entry?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I've got a django project set up as follows:

`myapp.models.py`

```
from django.db import models

class BaseModel(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Source(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    base_url = models.ForeignKey('URL', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class URL(BaseModel):
    url = models.TextField(max_length=512, unique=True)
    url_source = models.ForeignKey('Source', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

In a separate functions.py file, I've got the following script which is intended to populate the database with some initial *known* data that will be referenced by all new data. i.e. indexing unknown number and target `URL` links found from a number of known `Source` websites.

`functions.py`

```
# Create non-runtime db access
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "MY_PROJECT.settings")
import django
django.setup()

from MYAPP import models

sources = {
        'website-one': {'base_url': 'https://www.website-one.com'},
        'website-two': {'base_url': 'https://www.website-two.com'},
        'website-three': {'base_url': 'https://www.website-three.com'},
    }
    for name, meta in sources.items():

        new_url = models.URL.objects.create(url=meta['base_url'])

        print(new_url.id)
```

When this runs, the `print` function returns `None`, `None`, `None` which I interpret as meaning the new `URL` objects haven't been saved. If I inspect the database afterward I can see that each object is successfully created and has an `id` field as expected.

My intent is to use this:

```
new_url = models.URL.objects.create(url=meta['base_url'])
```

To add a reference to a new `Source` in the next line as such:

```
new_source = models.Source.objects.create(name=name, base_url=new_url)
```

Why doesn't this work?

**NOTE**

After the script runs, I can see in the database that all new `URL` objects have been committed and have `id` fields assigned as expected, though they cannot be immediately referenced in the script (the issue.)

**NOTE**

When doing this:

```
new_url = models.URL.objects.create(url=meta['base_url'])
new_url.save()
```

I get a `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed` error which seemingly indicates that an entry for the new `URL` does exist.

Comment: Are you explicitly creating that `id` field on purpose? If you have non-AutoField ID field, you'll need to specify their values by hand.

Comment: I am, but I didn't realize that I hadn't set `id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)`. Solved the problem. Make it an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Done. Glad to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have

```
id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

in the base model.

If you have non-AutoField ID field, you'll need to specify their values by hand.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't import your URL model in functions.py

Comment: You were right, though that was just an error on my behalf. The `models` were imported and the `URL` was referenced as `models.URL`. I updated the question to reflect that, though the issue was as @AKX pointed out.